# Header file not found while path is included in configure command

Tags: gcc, makefile, configure

Trying to build FFMPeG from source with this configure command

```
./configure --x86asmexe=/home/mahmood/yasm-1.3.0/bin/yasm --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp \
--extra-cflags=-I"~/cuda-10.1.168/include,~/nv_codec_headers/include/ffnvcodec/" \
--extra-ldflags=-L"~/cuda-10.1.168/lib64/,~/nv_codec_headers/lib/pkgconfig/"
```

I get this error in config.log which it can not find npp.h. Please note that additional include folders are given to the gcc command and npp.h actually exists in the path I gave.

```
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE \
-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -DPIC -I~/cuda-10.1.168/include,~/nv_codec_headers/include/ffnvcodec/ \
-std=c11 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -pthread -c \
-o /tmp/ffconf.dk4hdPMF/test.o /tmp/ffconf.dk4hdPMF/test.c
/tmp/ffconf.dk4hdPMF/test.c:1:10: fatal error: npp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <npp.h>
          ^~~~~~~
```

And npp.h is here

```
$ ls -l ~/cuda-10.1.168/include/npp.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood 2864 Dec 16 18:24 /home/mahmood/cuda-10.1.168/include/npp.h
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not so sure `-I` can take comma-separated directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a makefile question.

You have two problems.  First, you cannot pass multiple paths to the `-I` option by separating them with commas, like `-I<dir1>,<dir2>`.  You have to use multiple `-I` options, like `-I<dir1> -I<dir2>`.

Second, the `~` is a special character *expanded by the shell* before it invokes the compiler, and the shell will not expand the `~` everywhere in the command line.  For example if you run `echo foo~bar` or even `echo foo~/bar` the shell will not treat `~` as a reference to your home directory and will not expand it.  It's only treated specially if it's the *first* character in a word.  You need to either use the `$HOME` environment variable or else you need to add a space between the `-I` and the directory so that the `~` is the first character in the word: `-I$HOME/<dir1> -I$HOME/<dir2>` or `-I ~/<dir1> -I ~/<dir2>`.

If you use `$HOME` remember you need to escape the `$` in your make recipe.